# How do you solve the following separable differential equation: y'y = y + 1?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I just started learning about differential equations and encountered following equation:
$$ y'y = y +1 $$

Wolfram alpha provided the following explanation:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFyzF.png)

But I'm not sure how the integration is performed. What rules are used?
How does $\int{\frac{y'y}{y+1}dx}$ become $-\log(y + 1) + y$?

Comment: Because dx is canceled.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They use substitution, namely that $y'dx = dy$, so you can rewrite
$$
\int\frac{y'y}{y+1}dx = \int\frac{y}{y+1} dy = \int\left(\frac{-1}{y+1} + 1\right)dy
$$
Using this substitution to solve a differential equation is called "solution by separation", and an equation where this is possible to do is called a "separable equation". The general requirement for a separable equation is that you can get the equation to the form $f(y)y' = g(x)$, which then becomes $\int f(y) dy = \int g(x)dx$.

Comment: Please see my answer that explains why WA's solution is incorrect and gives a sketch of the proper proof.

Comment: @user21820 It's true that WA missed the $y = -1$ solution, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: Well, if I ask you why $1 = 2$ you should tell me that it is false and why so. Here, the asker's question contains a false implicit assumption that the solution given by WA is correct. Are you saying you ought to ignore that error? Arguably even your answer is wrong, regardless of whether you 'answered the question', because your equation is simply logically invalid when $y = -1$. I'm just fussy over logical correctness, okay? =)

Comment: OK, let's fuss: the question, as I read it, was really "How do you get from $\int\frac{y'y}{y+1}dx$ to $-\ln(y+1)+y+C$?" plus some context on how he got to that stage. If someone asks "how does this step work in this proof that $2=1$?", I would tell them how that step worked.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. I just meant that on top of that one should tell them where the erroneous steps in the whole proof that $2 = 1$ are, especially if they don't seem to acknowledge that it is wrong! The point is that most people don't realize that the method they are taught to solve differential equations is flawed. I myself was taught this flawed way and had nobody to teach me how to do it correctly. Teaching is not only about answering the students' questions but also identifying and correcting their misconceptions that they don't realize they have.

Comment: @user21820 You got me there.

Answer (score 12):

Note that Wolfram Alpha is wrong. The correct real-valued solutions are $x = y - \ln|y+1| + c$ for some constant $c$, or $y = -1$. The reason it is missed the latter is that the technique of separable variables (equivalent the substitution rule) is applied wrongly. One can only carry out that solution where $y \ne -1$. Then one needs to check that those regions of the solution do not touch $y = -1$ and hence there is no bifurcation. See [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/7984) for an example with bifurcation. In general Wolfram Alpha always gets this kind of differential equation wrong, though arguably in the real world functions are sufficiently smooth and so the strange solutions are never physical.

Here's the proper solution:
$\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}$

---

Take any real variables $x,y$ such that $\lfrac{dy}{dx} y = y+1$.

Let $D$ be any open subset of the curve defined by $(x,y)$ that does not intersect the line defined by $y+1=0$.

Then $\lfrac{dy}{dx} \lfrac{y}{y+1} = 1$ on $D$.

Thus $\int \lfrac{dy}{dx} \lfrac{y}{y+1}\ dx = \int 1\ dx = x+k$ on $D$, for some constant $k$.

Also $\int \lfrac{y}{y+1} \lfrac{dy}{dx}\ dx = \int \lfrac{y}{y+1}\ dy$ on $D$, because $\lfrac{y}{y+1}$ is continuous on $D$.

And $\int \lfrac{y}{y+1}\ dy = \int (1-\lfrac{1}{y+1})\ dy = y-\ln|y+1| + m$ on $D$, for some constant $m$.

Thus $x = y-\ln|y+1| + c$ on $D$, for some constant $c$.

Note that $x = y-\ln|y+1|+c \to \infty$ as $y \to -1$, and hence the above solution on $D$ cannot be extended to any solution that includes a point on the line defined by $y=-1$.

Thus there is no bifurcation.

Also note that if $y = -1$ at any point then $\lfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$ and hence $y$ is constant there.

Thus the only other solution is $y = -1$.

Comment: Often in "real world" problems, the degenerate solution is the *only* solution that is "physically reasonable". e.g. you have a requirement that the solution be a bounded function

Comment: Also, to be fair, the $y=-1$ solution corresponds to $c = -\infty$, although I am unsure if it is mathematica's intent to leave it like that.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say your answer is unuseful, I was just adding some clarification.

Comment: @Hurkyl: No WA really gets such questions wrong. As I said, if you try a differential equation with actual bifurcation, such as the one I gave in my linked post, it won't find the right solutions at all.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Anyway I'd be interested to know if you have an example of a differential equation where a non-meromorphic solution is physically meaningful.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment. Are you saying $y=-1$ is the strange solution, or $x = y - \ln|y+1|+c$ is the strange solution?

Comment: @Hurkyl: Oh I was the one misunderstanding your comment; I thought you were referring to the general case where bifurcation usually occurs with associate degenerate solutions. In this case $y = -1$, while degenerate, does not 'participate' in any bifurcation, so it's a perfectly meaningful solution. Also, all the solutions for this equation are meromorphic, whereas in general bifurcation leads to non-meromorphic (and from what I know non-physical) solutions.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}y=y+1$$
$$\int\frac{y}{y+1}dy=\int dx$$
$$\int1-\frac{1}{y+1}dy=\int dx$$
$$y-\log(y+1)=x+c$$

Comment: Please see my answer that explains why WA's solution is incorrect and gives a sketch of the proper proof. The error is more obvious in your presentation because you divided by $y+1$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\int\dfrac y{y+1}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}\cdot dx=\int\dfrac{(y+1-1)}{y+1}dy=?$$